# Tuple inference fails

Tags: scala, generics, tuples

Hi so I have a trait with generics +T and +U.

```
def test[I >: T, V >: U](e: Traversable[I], f: V)
def test[I >: T, V >: U](e: (Traversable[I], V))
def test[I >: T, V >: U](e: Tuple2[Traversable[I], V])
```

The first one works fine. 
The last 2 however both spit out:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (String, Int)
[error]  required: (Traversable[?], ?)
```

Why can scala not infer the types in the 2nd and 3rd examples? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a compiler bug to me. I don't see a reason why it can convert `String` to `Traversable` in the first case but not the other two cases.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles in Scala 2.12.3 without errors:

```
trait MyTrait[+T, +U] {
  def test[I >: T, V >: U](e: Traversable[I], f: V)
  def test1[I >: T, V >: U](e: (Traversable[I], V))
  def test2[I >: T, V >: U](e: Tuple2[Traversable[I], V])
}
```

Comment: The compile error occurs when you call `test1(("hello", 42))` on a `MyTrait[Char, Int]`.

Comment: This is exactly it. Maybe its a version specific bug?